# Using devise for more than one models in rails app

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

hello I am new to rails and i have installed rails version 4. I would like to know that I  am making project for teacher n students. Can I apply devise gem to both the models teachers and students. The main thing in my project is that both teachers and students sign up form need to be different. Then can anyone tell me the procedure of how to apply devise such that sign up forms can be created differently...

Comment: yes you can use that with devise. a polymorphic association will be usefull

Comment: how to do that? any reference

Comment: Actually, to be right. The main model has to be User. Students and Teachers are just roles. Check out CanCan

Comment: if I make user model then can I create diff sign up form for both user?

Comment: I think this is a common question and you can figure out yourself by ... google ;). You can try [Devise README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models)

Comment: I searched but nothing found really cool which I can apply . My actual problem is  created two user teacher n students but I want to authenticate them using devise. But when i apply devise to them the sign up form does not change n I want different sign up forms for both users

Comment: In one answer it was written that it can be done by changing in devise.rb that config.scope = true will solve the problem but nothing happened in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise can work for you, but you will have to run through some tutorials. Your request for a complete how-to is too broad for an Stack Overflow question. http://railsapps.github.io/tutorial-rails-devise-rspec-cucumber.html#authorization

You may also want to look at a gem to manage permissions, as Devise is more for authentication. My personal favorite is **[the_role](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role)**, but others like **[cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)** very much.